# How to detect overload resolution failure?

Tags: c++, c++20, overload-resolution, stdtuple

Consider the following code snippet:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename ...>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <>
struct always_false<decltype([] {})> : std::true_type {};

template <typename ...Ts>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = always_false<Ts...>::value;

template <typename>
struct type_wrapper {};

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_index_impl_base
{
    auto foo(type_wrapper<T>) -> std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
};

template <typename ...Ts>
struct tuple_index_impl_base_fallback
{
    auto foo(...)
    {
        static_assert(always_false_v<Ts...>, "Type not exist.");
    }
};

template <typename, typename ...>
struct tuple_index_impl;

template <std::size_t ...Is, typename ...Ts>
struct tuple_index_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> : tuple_index_impl_base<Is, Ts>..., tuple_index_impl_base_fallback<Ts...>
{
    using tuple_index_impl_base<Is, Ts>::foo...;
    using tuple_index_impl_base_fallback<Ts...>::foo;
};

template <typename, typename>
struct tuple_index;

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct tuple_index<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> : decltype(std::declval<tuple_index_impl<std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<Ts...>>>, Ts...>>().foo(std::declval<type_wrapper<T>>())) {};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline constexpr std::size_t tuple_index_v = tuple_index<T, U>::value;
```

Which implements a metafunction `tuple_index` to get the index corresponding to the type in a `std::tuple`.

It works fine if the type exists and exists only once in the tuple:

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t i = tuple_index_v<char&, std::tuple<int, float, char, char&, const char*, char>>;    // i == 3
```

And if the type does not exist, the `static_assert` would be triggered and print an error message:

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t i = tuple_index_v<long, std::tuple<int, float, char, char&, const char*, char>>;    //  error C2338: static_assert failed: 'Type not exist.'
```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oPGrfzsMK))

However, if the type exist more than once, instead of printing a user friendly error message, the compiler would starting compain that `ambiguous call to overloaded function`:

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t i = tuple_index_v<char, std::tuple<int, float, char, char&, const char*, char>>;    //  error C2668: 'tuple_index_impl_base_fallback<int,float,char,char &,const char *,char>::foo': ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rerTT445P))

Seems if there are two identical functions in the overload set, the compiler won't choose the fallback function (`tuple_index_impl_base_fallback<Ts...>::foo(...)` in this example.).

How to detect overload resolution failure under this scenario and catch it with a `static_assert`?

Comment: I'm just reading through your code now. One little thing that I'd point out is that `std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<Ts...>>` is equivalent to `sizeof...(Ts)`. You might want to indent your code a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: In C++20, there is no need to use such old-fashioned metaprogramming to implement it, simply using a for-loop to iterate over the type will be enough. You can refer to [libstdc++'s implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/0c1b0a23f1fe7db6a2e391b7cb78cff900377772/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/utility.h#L110) of such utilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the overload resolution would succeed with a `requires` expression:

```cpp
template <std::size_t ...Is, typename ...Ts>
struct tuple_index_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> : tuple_index_impl_base<Is, Ts>..., tuple_index_impl_base_fallback<Ts...>
{
    using tuple_index_impl_base<Is, Ts>::foo...;
    using tuple_index_impl_base_fallback<Ts...>::foo;

    template<typename T>
    static auto foo2() {
        using wrapper = type_wrapper<T>;
        static_assert(requires(tuple_index_impl i, wrapper w) { i.foo(w); }, "Duplicate type");
        return tuple_index_impl{}.foo(wrapper{});
    }
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct tuple_index<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> : decltype(tuple_index_impl<std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<Ts...>>>, Ts...>::template foo2<T>()) {};
```

Comment: You should add a working demo showing how to use it.